# What formula in one cell shows "break even" point in an mortgage amortization table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm making a mortgage amortization calculator thing.
Column A is the payment month. 1,2,3,...211,212,213...
Column G is the remaining principal.  So, it's a decreasing number going down.
Column K is "current investment." So, this number goes up as payments are made.

I trying to make a formula in cell I4 that will tell me where the "break even" point is... Where the value in K becomes >= G.

At that break even point cell I4 should report the month number.  One number at that point.

I put this in a column so I can see where the break even point is by just scrolling down looking at the result:
=IF(G11>=K11,"Keep Going","Break Even or Better")
But I just want one value in cell A4.

I tried this in cell A4, but I don't know how to reference that one point where it goes from not true to true.  This isn't right, anyway.:
=IF(K11:K200>=G11:G200,A34/12,0)

I need cell A4 (I have labeled as "Pay off in months") to report the month number from column A when the number in column K first is >= the number in column G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the month:

```
=<payments>-SUMPRODUCT(--(G:G<K:K))+1
```

Where `<payments>` is the number of months payments are amortized over

Answer (score 2):

[image: Mock up Example]

Suppose you have the above mortgage amortisation schedule, and you have the following **named ranges** in your excel worksheet:

- **RemaPri** being the range of remaining principals in `Column G`;
- **CurrInv** being the range of current investments in `Column K`;
- **MthNo** being the month numbers in `Column A`;
- **Comment** being the comments (`Keep Going` or `Break Even or Better`) in `Column L`

You can use one of the following three formulas to return the month of break even:

```
{=INDEX(MthNo,MATCH(TRUE,CurrInv>=RemaPri,0))}
```

> This is an **array formula** which needs to be confirmed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the formula bar. The logic is to compare the current investments with remaining principals, use **MATCH** function to find the first `TRUE` result, and then use **INDEX** function to return the corresponding month number.

```
=INDEX(MthNo,MATCH("Break Even or Better",Comment,0))
```

> The logic is to use **MATCH** function to find the first `Break Even or Better` from the `Comment` column, and then use **INDEX** function to return the corresponding month number.

```
=Term-SUMPRODUCT((CurrInv<RemaPri)*1)
```

> Need to give credit to @cybernetic.nomad as this was his idea. The logic is to use **SUMPRODUCT** function to 'count' all `FALSE` values from the comparison between current investments and remaining principals, which would the same as the total number of `Keep Going` in the `Comment` column, and then subtract this number by the total number of months to get the first month that the investment is break even.

Please note in my example I have presumed the current investments is the sum of interest and principal. The answer may defer if current investment only represent principal payment, but the formulas will still work in this case.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you for the very, very helpful answers.  These methods will help me a lot.  I would like to have marked your's as the "answer" but in fairness to cybernetic.nomad, his answer did work and he answered first.  So, thank you cybernetic!  Terry W, your answer is very helpful because of all of the descriptions you included.  Big thanks to you, Terry!

Comment: @DavidMegnin No fuss happy to help :)